# Access Changed HiddenField Value in JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a JavaScript that relies on a `HiddenField` value. This `HiddenField`, we will call it `needUpdate`, is a boolean that gets set to true when a `div` on my page needs to be updated with JavaScript. `needUpdate` is located in an `UpdatePanel` which is updated through a `Timer`. I have tried two different methods and both half work. The first is to place the JavaScript outside the update panel and use my `PageRequestManager` instance to run the script like so:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function DoUpdate(sender, args)
    {
        if ('<%= needUpdate.Value %>' == 'true') {
            // Code here... //
        }
    }
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(DoUpdate);
</script>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="replay" runat="server" Visible="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="replayTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="needUpdate" runat="server" Value="false"/>
        <asp:Timer ID="replayTimer" runat="server" Interval="500" OnTick="replayTimer_Tick" />
        <!-- More Stuff Here -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div id="divToUpdate"></div>
```

Now the above runs the script but the value in `needUpdate` is never changed, even though it is changed on the back end. So, I tried the next bit of code where I placed the script in the `ContentTemplate` area of my `UpdatePanel`

```
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="needUpdate" runat="server" Value="false"/>
        <asp:Timer ID="replayTimer" runat="server" Interval="500" OnTick="replayTimer_Tick" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function DoUpdate()
            {
                if ('<%= hf_needUpdate.Value %>' == 'true') {
                    // Code here... //
                }
            }
            DoUpdate();
        </script>
        <!-- More Stuff Here -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

While this updated the script area the code was never called. Any thoughts on how to get a value changed by an `UpdatePanel` to feed a JavaScript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hardcoding a false result into the JavaScript if statement. What gets into the page for:

`'<%= hf_needUpdate.Value %>' == 'true'` ??

`'false' == 'true'` ??

This never changes you need to get the current value of the hidden field.

```
var needUpdate = document.getElementById("needUpdate").value;
if(needUpdate == "true) {
     // Do work
}
```

Comment: Your answer works perfectly with just one change. Instead of using the `getElementById("needUpdate")` I used `getElementById('<%=hf_needUpdate.ClientID%>')`